# VBA: Removing values from a multi-select field

Tags: vba, excel

I have a page in my workbook where certain cells are multi-select. Users can choose values from a dropdown list and it will append them and format them to be uploaded into our system. It works great -- but there's just one problem. There's no way to remove a single value currently. If a user selects the wrong value from the dropdown, they'd have to delete and start over. Is there a way to remove individual values? Here's the current multi-select code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim strSep As String
Dim strSep2 As String
Dim header As String
Dim MatchField As Range
Dim AnsType As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

strSep = Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34)
strSep2 = "," & Chr(34)

header = Me.Cells(11, Target.Column).Value 
Set MatchField = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("User Fields").Range("B16:B100").Find(header) 

If Not MatchField Is Nothing Then
    Set AnsType = MatchField.Offset(0, 2) 
End If

Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error Resume Next

If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler 

Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then 
   'do nothing
Else 'cell has data validation
    If InStr(1, AnsType, "Multiple") > 0 Then 'Determines if current column corresponds to a multi-select field

    newVal = Target.Value 
    Application.Undo 
    oldVal = Target.Value 
    Target.Value = newVal 

    If newVal = "" Then
        'do nothing
    Else 
        If oldVal = "" Then 
            Target.Value = newVal 
        ElseIf InStr(1, oldVal, newVal) = 0 Then 
            If InStr(1, oldVal, Chr(34)) > 0 Then 
                Target.Value = oldVal & strSep2 & newVal & Chr(34) 
            Else 
                Target.Value = Chr(34) & oldVal & strSep & newVal & Chr(34) 
            End If
        Else
            Target.Value = oldVal
        End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: yes, it is possible, but I could not figure out quickly how your code should work since I don't have the whole Excel file here. I have a code like that, but I use listbox. Can you explain how your code is supposed to work?

Comment: Ditto...  I think you have cells with drop-down boxes in them, and each drop-down has different elements.  He can choose several elements from different drop-downs, and these can be formatted and concatenated together to be sent to another system.  Right?  And once the user selects an item from a particular dropdown and it is sent to the other system, then you want that item to be removed from that drop down.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @JohnMuggins Not quite, but close. There's another sub on this page (selectionchange event) that dynamically adjusts data validation based on lists on another page. Let's say my list is Business Units. When a client uses this drop down in the cell, they can select more than one business unit. The code allows them to do so and it will format it like "Unit 1","Unit2" which allows us to upload the data into our site. We need to be able to unselect Unit 2 in some way and have it removed. Directly editing/deleting doesn't work b/c "Unit 1" isn't in the list, Unit 1 is.

Comment: Let me try again:  A user has a drop-down list with several items.  He can choose Multiple items.  If he mistakenly chooses an incorrect item, then you want a way for him to deselect that item?  I'll take a look at n alternative.  Give me a day or two.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the "If" statement that prohibits doubles of the same item to be able to delete it from the string.  Try the following code, leaving the doubles statement commented out.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Updated: 2016/4/12
    Dim xRng As Range
    Dim xValue1 As String
    Dim xValue2 As String
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRng = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, xRng) Is Nothing Then
        xValue2 = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        xValue1 = Target.Value
        Target.Value = xValue2
        If xValue1 <> "" Then
            If xValue2 <> "" Then
'                If xValue1 = xValue2 Or _
'                   InStr(1, xValue1, ", " & xValue2) Or _
                   InStr(1, xValue1, xValue2 & ",") Then
                If InStr(1, xValue1, xValue2 & ",") > 0 Then
                    xValue1 = Replace(xValue1, xValue2 & ", ", "") ' If it's in the middle with comma
                    Target.Value = xValue1
                    GoTo jumpOut
                End If
                If InStr(1, xValue1, ", " & xValue2) > 0 Then
                    xValue1 = Replace(xValue1, ", " & xValue2, "") ' If it's at the end with a comma in front of it
                    Target.Value = xValue1
                    GoTo jumpOut
                End If
                If xValue1 = xValue2 Then ' If it is the only item in string
                    xValue1 = ""
                    Target.Value = xValue1
                    GoTo jumpOut
                End If
                Target.Value = xValue1 & ", " & xValue2
            End If
jumpOut:
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I forgot to mention:  To remove an item from the target.cell string, simply select it again from the drop box.  It will search the string for that item and delete it from the target.cell if found, or add it to the target.cell if not found in the instr function.

Answer (score 0):

I had a few issues with John's answer, where values like "707" and "7" would cause problems. Here's the script I ended up using. Note that the implementation of the first part is a bit different too.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Code by Sumit Bansal from https://trumpexcel.com
' To allow multiple selections in a Drop Down List in Excel (without repetition)
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Column = 9 Then
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
        GoTo Exitsub
    ElseIf Target.Value = "" Then
        GoTo Exitsub
    Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Newvalue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        Oldvalue = Target.Value
        Target.Value = Newvalue
       If Oldvalue <> "" Then
            If Newvalue <> "" Then
                If InStr(1, Oldvalue, ", " & Newvalue & ",") > 0 Then
                    Oldvalue = Replace(Oldvalue, Newvalue & ", ", "") ' If it's in the middle with comma
                    Target.Value = Oldvalue
                    GoTo jumpOut
                End If
                If Left(Oldvalue, Len(Newvalue & ", ")) = Newvalue & ", " Then
                    Oldvalue = Replace(Oldvalue, Newvalue & ", ", "") ' If it's at the start with comma
                    Target.Value = Oldvalue
                    GoTo jumpOut
                End If
                If Right(Oldvalue, Len(", " & Newvalue)) = ", " & Newvalue Then
                    Oldvalue = Left(Oldvalue, Len(Oldvalue) - Len(", " & Newvalue)) ' If it's at the end with a comma in front of it
                    Target.Value = Oldvalue
                    GoTo jumpOut
                End If
                If Oldvalue = Newvalue Then ' If it is the only item in string
                    Oldvalue = ""
                    Target.Value = Oldvalue
                    GoTo jumpOut
                End If
                Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
            End If
jumpOut:
        End If
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```